# Button for backspace for calculator in Android

Tags: android, calculator

I'm developing a calculator in which I want to add a backspace button. On clicking on backspace button elements of `EditText` will be delete one-by-one. But I'm not getting how to write the code for this. Please suggest a solution?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214855/append-backspace-in-edittext) could help.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
EditText edit;

...

String txt = edit.getText();
txt = txt.length() > 1 ? txt.substring(0, txt.length() - 2) : "0";
edit.setText(txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
binding.idImageViewBackSpace.setOnClickListener {
        val CursorPos = binding.InputTextView.selectionStart
        val length = binding.InputTextView.text.length

        if (CursorPos != 0 && length != 0) {
            val selection: Editable? = binding.InputTextView.text
            selection?.replace(CursorPos - 1, CursorPos, "")
            binding.InputTextView.text = selection
            binding.InputTextView.setSelection(CursorPos - 1)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).